# Backbone.js newbie - cannot get model error event to fire

Tags: backbone.js

I am looking at backbone.js for the first time. I'm currently looking at model validation, but this test script which I've taken directly from a teaching text is not firing the error event as expected.

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // If you return a string from the validate function,
    // Backbone will throw an error
    validate: function(attributes) {
        if (attributes.age < 0 && attributes.name != "Dr Manhatten") {
            return "You can't be negative years old";
        }
    },
    initialize: function() {
        alert("Welcome to this world");
        this.bind("error", function(model, error) {
            // We have received an error, log it, alert it or forget it :)
            alert(error);
        });
    }
});

var person = new Person;
person.set({ name: "Mary Poppins", age: -1 });
// Will trigger an alert outputting the error

var person = new Person;
person.set({ name: "Dr Manhatten", age: -1 });
// God have mercy on our souls
```

My page for testing this is dead simple as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/test4.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

All I'm seeing are the two "Welcome to this world" alerts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your source code is probably based on an older version of Backbone, [Model.validate](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate) changed quite a bit over time.

From the [changelog](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog)

> 0.9.10  : Model validation is now only enforced by default in Model#save and no longer enforced by default 
>   upon construction or in Model#set, unless the `{validate:true}` option is passed.

and

> **validate** *model.validate(attributes, options)*
>   This method is left undefined, and you're encouraged to override it with your custom
>   validation logic, if you have any that can be performed in JavaScript.
>   By default validate is called before save, but **can also be called
>   before set if {validate:true} is passed**. [...] **Failed validations trigger an "invalid" event**.

So :

- to validate your model when setting attributes, use a `validate:true` option
- bind to the `invalid` event
- and use [Events.on](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) instead of the deprecated bind

Your code could look like this

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // If you return a string from the validate function,
    // Backbone will throw an error
    validate: function(attributes) {
        if (attributes.age < 0 && attributes.name != "Dr Manhatten") {
            return "You can't be negative years old";
        }
    },
    initialize: function() {
        console.log("Welcome to this world");
        this.on("invalid", function(model, error) {
            // We have received an error, log it, alert it or forget it :)
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
});

var person = new Person;
person.set({ name: "Mary Poppins", age: -1 }, {validate:true});
// Will trigger an alert outputting the error

var person = new Person;
person.set({ name: "Dr Manhatten", age: -1 }, {validate:true});
```

And a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/udm8A/ (be sure to open a console, I converted the `alert` calls to `console.log`)

Comment: Thanks, looks like I paid $3 for a seriously out-of-date tutorial! Much appreciated.

Comment: @tomtroughton To be fair, 0.9.10 is only 2 months old :)